# How to get duration in microseconds

Tags: php, time, php-5.3, microtime

I want to measure how long a specified part of my php script takes, e.g.

```
$startTime = microtime(true);
//some operations which needs 0.1 to 100 seconds to run
$endTime = microtime(true);
```

How can I get the duration **in microseconds as an integer**?

This does not work:

```
$duration = (int)($endTime - $startTime);
```

Comment: Why not use `round` ... `$duration = round($endTime - $startTime);` ... it returns a float type, but it will return an integer ...

Comment: you are getting the time as an integer, you just have a very basic misunderstanding of what an integer is. anything less that 1 will be set to 0 when you cast it with (int). you probably want something more like $duration = $endTime-$startTime; $duration = number_format($duration,2);

Comment: Wait, let's define what you mean by 'microseconds as an integer' ... if the script takes .23 seconds to run are you wanting to see 230?

Comment: @dleiftah yes, I need the microseconds (2300) not the seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want microseconds as an integer:

```
$duration = round(($endTime - $startTime) * 1000000)
```

Comment: So you got milliseconds. It would be *pow(10,6).

Comment: perfect! Also works: (int)(($endTime - $startTime) * pow(10,6))

Comment: As a note ... casting as a int will always round down, so there is a chance that the two will produce different results ...